# Использование и примеры DetailView yii2-detail-view

Tags: yii2, view, views

Здравствуйте.

Хочу использовать [виджет](http://demos.krajee.com/detail-view) DetailView для Yii2.

В документации [о нём](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/output-data-widgets/#detailview) написано мало.

Можно привести пример простого использования. Как я понял, эту часть кода нужно вставлять и настраивать в модели?

```
echo DetailView::widget([
'model' => $model,
'attributes' => [
    'title',                                           // title свойство (обычный текст)
    'description:html',                                // description свойство, как HTML
    [                                                  // name свойство зависимой модели owner
        'label' => 'Owner',
        'value' => $model->owner->name,            
        'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'bg-red'],     // настройка HTML атрибутов для тега, соответсвующего value
        'captionOptions' => ['tooltip' => 'Tooltip'],  // настройка HTML атрибутов для тега, соответсвующего label
    ],
    'created_at:datetime',                             // дата создания в формате datetime
],
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да. Эту часть кода нужно вставлять на view. Если когда-нибудь использовали GridView то используйте DetailView по аналогии.